# Why is Log4Net never throwing exceptions

Tags: .net, log4net

Last time I configured Log4Net is two weeks ago.
I have always the same problem: getting it running.

Last time I installed the nuget.
My BaseClass BaseController got
 `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]` before the namespace and a private member with `private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);`

Web.Config as always with the correct section and a few appenders:
`<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>`
 And as always its not working without any hint what could be the problem.
 No file created with rollingfileappander, traceappender or any other appender. Its always the same with Log4Net: Find the error. 

Why is this framework not throwing exceptions?

Comment: May be its logging somewhere, after all it is a logger. You can also check out the eventvwr

Comment: Logging libraries are very humble, they don't consider themselves important enough to prevent the program from running.  And they have a lot to be humble about, programmers make little effort to find out how they work or read the library's FAQ to get help.

Answer (score 4):

Why is Log4Net never throwing exceptions?

Log4net is a best-effort and fail-stop logging system which means that it is designed to not interact with your normal program flow.

You can enable internal log4net logging to see why logging is failing:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

And

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
        <listeners>
            <add 
                name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

in your configuration.

[log4net faq](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html)

Comment: Wow, thats nice. Thanks. But log is not saying why it doesnt log.

Comment: Great and succinct answer! Thanks, that helped me find the reason why some appender is not working.